# Javascript Break Statement

Tags: javascript, loops, break

If you use the break statement will it break all if...else...if else statements and all loops? If so how can you break just a single if/loop.

```
while(test here){if({break;}don't break;)}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `break` statement will only break out of the one loop in that you put it in. It doesn't affect if/else statements. If you want to break an outer loop you can use labels, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564838/897024).

```
while(true){
    if(something) {
        break;
        console.log("this won't ever be executed");
    } else {
        console.log("still in loop");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

The break statement will break the loop and continue executing the code that follows after the loop (if any).

Check: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Answer (score 2):

`break;` will jump to the end of the deepest containing `for`, `do`, `while` or `switch` statement.

`break label;` will jump to the end of the labelled one.

`if` doesn't matter.

It's an error to `break` to a non-existant label, or if the relevant `for`, `do`, `while`, or `switch` is in a different function body.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a break for if statements. You'll have to restructure your if statement to only execute the code you need.

There is, however, a `continue;` which skips to the next iteration of the loop, while `break;` quits the loop entirely.