# How portable are JavaScript break labels?

Tags: javascript, language-features

A less well-known feature of JavaScript is that you can use labels to `break` and `continue` out of nested loop and switch statements:

```
i_loop: for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    j_loop: for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (i == 3 && i < j)
            break i_loop;
    }
}
```

This feature is the answer to:

- [Best way to break from nested loops in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183161/149391)
- [How to break nested loops in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1564818/149391)

My question is, how portable is it?  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3666y5k%28v=vs.94%29) has a long list of supported IE versions.  The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) says it was implemented in JavaScript 1.2 (released in 1997), and that it is in ECMA-262, 3rd Edition (1999).  Going by this, labels should be extremely portable, but can I count on it?

Comment: Why would you think you couldn't count on it? I'd be amazed if you could find a JS implementation that doesn't support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break), a labelled break is supported since the "ECMA-262, Edition 3" standard (published in December 1999, so I believe there should not be a single browser out there that does not support it :))