# Should I Ever Use Labels In Javascript? (If So, When?)

Tags: javascript, labeled-statements

**Backstory:** Once again I was reading in my Javascript book and I bumped into something that the book didn't explain very well, and that I wasn't able to find any good examples of online.

**Example from Book:**

```
parser:
    while(token != null) {
    // Code omitted here
}
```

The only paragraph used to explain this code said that by using a label I could refer to a statement elsewhere in my code and that labels are "**commonly**" used for loops. I've never seen a label used before let alone "commonly."

**My question is:** Are labels used and if so what is a good example of a place where I would want to use one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only time I've really seen it is in a nested loop or if statement you can use labels to break to a specific one for example:

```
function foo ()
{
    dance:
    for(var k = 0; k < 4; k++){
        for(var m = 0; m < 4; m++){
            if(m == 2){
                break dance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the label "dance" lets you break to that point specifically if m == 2.

In my experience I would not say they are very common.

Example taken from here: [How to break nested loops in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564818/how-to-break-2-loops-in-javascript)

Perhaps better example here: [Best way to break from nested loops in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183161/best-way-to-break-from-nested-loops-in-javascript/183197#183197) at the second answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see why it would be useful in this case.