# Javascript won't exit do while loop

Tags: javascript

So I'm making a browser based game. I want it to display a prompt which will only move on to the next bit of code if a correct answer is inputted. However despite a correct answer the prompt displays, stuck in an infinite loop.

Here is the code.

```
do {
var cavalry = prompt("Now you need to deploy your troops. They wait for your command. First how shall you deploy your cavalry? -all left -all right -split evenly -stronger left -stronger right").toLowerCase();

switch(cavalry) {
    case 'all left':
        console.log("Your chose all left.");
        break;

    case 'all right':
        console.log("You chose all right.");
        break;

     case 'split evenly':
        console.log("You chose split evenly.");
        break;

    case 'stronger left':
        console.log("You chose stronger left.");
        break;

    case 'stronger right':
        console.log("You chose stronger right.");
        break;

    default:
        alert("That is not an option");
        console.log("Please choose one of the options.");
        break;
   }

}

while (cavalry!="all right" || cavalry!="all left" || cavalry!="stronger left" || cavalry!="stronger right" || cavalry!="split evenly");
```

Comment: Because while is always true?

Comment: Because the break is only breaking the switch statement, not the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well `cavalry!="all right" || cavalry!="all left"` is always true, since it can't be equal to both.

I think you meant `cavalry!="all right" && cavalry!="all left" && ...`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to break both the switch and the while loop if the user inputs something that is acceptable. You should check out labels

[How to break nested loops in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564818/how-to-break-2-loops-in-javascript)