# Is there a way to put a label AFTER all nested loops to break them all in one step?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to find a way to break nested loops better than this way

```
 var found = false;
  for(x=0; x<10; x++){
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        if(i===3){found =true; break;}; //break inner loop
    };//end of inner loop (i)
   if(found){break;}; // break outer loop
  };//end of outer loop for(x)
```

then I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564818/how-to-break-nested-loops-in-javascript) recommends to use labels to avoid more breaks and a Boolean like this

```
 //var found = false; // - using labels we saved this Boolean 
  exitlabel:
  for(x=0; x<10; x++){
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        if(i===3){break exitlabel;}; //jump to the label
    };//end of inner loop (i)
   //if(found){break;}; // - using labels we SAVED this if statement
  };//end of outer loop for(x)
```

but the problem is I can't but the label **after** the 2 loops to quit them . when I do this the browser tells me it can't find the label !
like this:

```
  for(x=0; x<10; x++){
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        if(i===3){break exitlabel;};
    };
  };
  exitlabel:  // ERROR
```

and butting the label before the loops will make the loops execute again from the beginning , unless I use a if statement and a Boolean right after the label and before the loops to bypass the 2 loops, with something like this

```
 var found = false;
 exitlabel:
 if(!found){
     for(x=0; x<10; x++){
       for(i=0; i<10; i++){
           if(i===3){found =true; break exitlabel;};
       };//end of inner loop (i)
     };//end of outer loop for(x)
 };// end of if statement
```

**IS there** a way to save a Boolean and avoid wrapping my loops inside a IF statement like this ,and just put the label after the 2 loops like C language?

*if this is a stupid question , please consider I'm very newbie, thanks.*

Comment: wrap everything inside a function and use return instead of break? That way the return is in scope of whatever you want to return. Also, have a look at Array.some() or Array.every() . It stops looping once a value returns as true / false.

Comment: @Shilly you beat me by few secs. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/8ve4fuxo/)

Comment: Why do you think putting the label before the loops makes them execute again? That's just not the case. `break` isn't `goto`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is there a way to put a label AFTER all nested loops to break them all in one step?*

By using the `break` statement as you already are, you can break the outer loop. It doesn't need to come after. This makes it halt immediately when you use `break exitlable`.

A simple test reveals this to be the case.

```js
exitlabel:
  for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      document.querySelector("pre").textContent += " " + i
      if (i === 3) {
        break exitlabel;
      }
    }
  }

  document.querySelector("pre").textContent += " after loop";
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

> *and butting the label before the loops will make the loops execute again from the beginning*

That's not true. By using `break` and referencing the label attached to the outer `for` statement, you're telling *that* loop to halt. It does not tell it to restart from the beginning.

What you're describing sounds more like `goto`, which JavaScript does not support.

Comment: ah , I'm sorry, in my code I had a big loop wrapped these 2 small loops and it was executing the 2 loops over and over , so I thought it is because the label was before the loops like `goto` in C , thanks for your time