# Javascript Break Statement Goodness

Tags: javascript, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to break from nested loops in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183161/best-way-to-break-from-nested-loops-in-javascript)

Is using labels to break loops, a good practice in javascript? Mention if it has any pros and cons

Ex:

```
var i, j;
outer:
    for(i in [0,1,2,3]) { 
    inner:
        for(j in [0,1,2,3]) { 
            if(j == 1) { 
                break outer; 
            }
        } 
        console.log("inner")
    } 
console.log("outer");
```

Comment: You should not use `for .. in` loops for arrays.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @people who closed the question I didn't ask how to exit javascript nested loops. I have asked whether it is a good practice to use labels or not. Take time to read questions before closing them.

Comment: Check this: https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/break-out-of-code-block-in-java-and-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the best way to break out of multiple loops.