# The 'for' loop only prints the first element of my array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem that I want to go through an array with a for loop, but for some reason the loop doesn't go through it and just prints the first element of the array everywhere.

Here is my array with the days:

```
readonly days: WeekDayName[] = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
```

And my functions is what it looks like now:

```
get dayName() {
  for (const { item, index } of this.days.map((item, index) => ({ item, index }))) {
    return (item);
  }
}
```

How can I solve not just print the first item everywhere?

Comment: How? Don't use `return`

Comment: `return` immediately terminates the function, so the `for..of` is ended before it does the full iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getter functions can't return the iteration values. You just can get an element in result of getters.

Answer (score 1):

Return statement gets you out of the loop. If you want to use an item that is iterated over in the for loop just store in a global variable.
and use break statement to fall out of the loop
Also important to notice that returns take you out of nested loops as well

Check this detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121529/in-a-nested-loop-js-function-does-return-exit-the-loop-or-the-whole-function) on return vs break

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the item after one iteration. What you should do is to create an empty array/map and on each iteration you can add the item to it. Then return that array.