# Break down this nested forloop

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

I'm trying to understand nested forloops and I found this code that should be simple and I want you to make sure I understand it.

```
var maximum = function(arr){
var out;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     out = true;
    console.log(i)
    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){

        if(arr[i] < arr[j]){
            // console.log(i, j)
            out = false;
             // console.log(arr[i], arr[j], " out ", out)
        }
    }
    if(out) return arr[i];
}
// return null;
}
 console.log(maximum([1,2,5]))
```

first of all i'm not sure why they define `out = true` but I wanted to undestand the looping right now

so for the first iteration

`i` is set  to 0  and `out` is set to true then we go into the second for loop

i= 0

inside the second forloop: `for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){`

we test `(arr[i] < arr[j])` 3 time for the length of the array

1st test in the inner loop :arr[0] = 1 < arr[0] = 1 ==false (so we do nothing?  shouldn't  out remain true  and we return `if(out) return arr[i];`?)

2nd test in the inner loop arr[0] = 1 < arr[1] = 2 == true.. set `out` to false

3rd test in the inner loop arr[0] = 1 < arr[2] = 5 == true .. set `out` to false

then we go to make `i` 1

then we test
is arr[i] = 2 < arr[j] which is 1 ? false we dont set out to false

is arr[i] = 2 < arr[j] which is 2 ? false we dont set out to false

is arr[i] = 2 < arr[j] which is 5? true we  set `out` to true

then we set `i` to 2
arr[2] = 5
is arr[2] which is 5 < arr[0] which is 1 this is false so out remains true

is arr[2] which is 5 < arr[1] which is 2 this is false so out remains true

is arr[2] which is 5 < arr[2] which is 5 this is false so out remains true

Is the corrected process for the nested loops?

Comment: This is horrible code. You should throw it away and find other code to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you've got the gist of it. The inner loop (the one that uses `j` as the counter variable) will run three times for every one time the outer loop ( the  `i` loop) runs.

A simpler way to understand this is to run this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1){
    console.log("outer loop")
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j += 1){
        console.log("inner loop")
    }
}
```

This allows you to focus just on the nested loops and not on trip-wire variables and such that are in the original code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: `first of all i'm not sure why they define out = true`  -- this is just an initialization which gets reset on each iteration of the outer loop.  If that value is the max, then out will remain true -- otherwise it will be false.

To answer your second question:  `1st test in the inner loop :arr[0] = 1 < arr[0] = 1 ==false (so we do nothing? shouldn't out remain true and we return if(out) return arr[i];?)`

Yes, you have the test correct -- the test is false so out remains true, but it doesn't drop down to the if(out) statement until the inner loop has completed its iterations.

To summarize the looping:  the inner loop compares the current value from the outer loop against all of the other values (including itself).  The outer loop is moving through each value (for a total of 3 times).

Comment: Thanks for your response. This part `1st test in the inner loop :arr[0] = 1 < arr[0] = 1 ==false (so we do nothing? shouldn't out remain true and we return if(out) return arr[i];?)`   you said :
"but it doesn't drop down to the if(out) statement until the inner loop has completed its iterations."  I'm thinking now that `out` doesnt become true because the next tests are false, right? and that makes `out` remain true because we initialized at the top.. lets say we test the last one where i = 2 which is the value 5 that fails all tests and out still remains true? that's how this works?

Comment: in the first loop, where the comparison is 1 < 1, out remains true.  however, on the next loop (and the one following), out starts out as true but is then set to false.  in the final outer loop where i = 2, the last test is 5 < 5, so out is does not get set to false and remains true.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Yes you are right.**

Long answer:

In a nut shell this function is trying to find the maximum in an array so it sets two for loops. `i` is the index for the first number and `j` is the index for the second number it's comparing `i` against.

The purpose of the `out` is simply to make sure it does not have to continue the outer loop if it finds it has the maximum value at `j`. It does a redundant check as you pointed out when `i` and `j` are the same value because it's, well, the same array and therefore the same number. Ideally it doesn't need to make this check, but whatever.

I think the biggest optimization that can be made as you may have noticed is that when `out` is set to false, does it really need to continue? We know it's not the max anymore so why bother? You can solve this really simply by making the [inner loop check the value of `out` and break out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19734110/1168661)

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     out = true;
    console.log(i)
    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length && out; j++){

        if(arr[i] < arr[j]){
            // console.log(i, j)
            out = false;
             // console.log(arr[i], arr[j], " out ", out)
        }
    }
    if(out) return arr[i];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see this gives the same result as the code in the question.I don't see a difference. can you show me with logs maybe how when `ou`t is set to false in the inner loop and when the outer `out`.is set to false. the outer loop doesn't need to continue.  when you say `does it really need to continue?` are you referring to do more inner loops. what do you mean?