# Breaking out of an inner foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to break out of an inner foreach loop using JavaScript/jQuery.

```
result.history.forEach(function(item) {
    loop2:
    item.forEach(function(innerItem) {
        console.log(innerItem);
        break loop2;
    });
});
```

This is resulting in the error `'Unidentified label loop2'`. it appears to be right before the loop which was what other questions were saying was the issue.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Edit: Correct, the foreach loop cant break in this way but a regular for loop can. This is working:

```
                        result.history.forEach(function(item) {
                            loop2:
                            for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                                var innerItem = item[i];
                                console.log(innerItem);
                                break loop2;
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: You can't use `break` to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/183197/5442132

Comment: @miqdadamirali Yes, that is the link I am referring to.

Comment: @Pointy [I believe you can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) but you really shouldn't.

Comment: @MikeC no, you can't `break` to a label across a function boundary: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.8

Comment: @Pointy Guess I should have verified before I opened my big mouth haha. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to be able to break an iteration, use `.every()` instead of `.forEach()`:

```
someArray.every(function(element) {
  if (timeToStop(element)) // or whatever
    return false;
  // do stuff
  // ...
  return true; // keep iterating
});
```

You could flip the `true`/`false` logic and use `.some()` instead; same basic idea.

Comment: Just as a note for posterity; this is ECMAScript 5.1 onwards, so no support below IE9.

Answer (score 5):

Can't do it. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behaviour, the .forEach() method is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead. If you are testing the array elements for a predicate and need a boolean return value, you can use every() or some() instead.

Comment: You can't break a `forEach` loop, but you can always use `.some()` or `.every()` instead.