# how to Break a For loop which has if statement in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

i have scenario where an IF statement is inside FOR loop. i want to break the FOR loop inside IF statement , how to achieve it?

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
   if(i==2){
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your example will already break the loop when `i==2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to break from nested loops in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183161/best-way-to-break-from-nested-loops-in-javascript)

Comment: Your scenario was right as per your need.What else you want other than this?If place the code any can help you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you got it right.

See MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

And this StackOverflow question about breaking inside nested loops if you need it: [Best way to break from nested loops in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183161/best-way-to-break-from-nested-loops-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use label for this scenario along with continue and break keywords, as shown below
It will skip when I is 1.

```
loop1:
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 if (i === 1) {
   continue loop1;
 }
}
```